# Pandas convert name where ID is the same and the name is different?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to clean up name values where I have the following situation.

```
     ID  name
1     1    Company
2     1    Company, LLC
```

I would like to normalize it so I have only one name like so:

```
     ID  name
1     1    Company
2     1    Company
```

Comment: check out FuzzyWuzzy [Here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy). How big is your dateframe? is it possible to have a clean list and "hardcode" the values you need to change?

Comment: Hey it's not too large probably around 300 values need to be changed. Is it possible to do this with a dict? Where the key is the ID and the value is the correct company name?

Comment: It will certainly be possible with a dictionary. It would be a lot of up-front manual work, but after that you would just make a condition to change the `Name` Column Based on the `ID` column using your dictionary. If your data does not change very much, this may be a good solution. However, if you have new names coming in, then keeping up with a dictionary would be a time-sink. If you need a more "permanent" solution, FuzzyWuzzy (or something like it) may be the place to go.

Answer (score 3):

This will keep the first element of each group and broadcast it along the entire size of your dataframe:

```
df
Out[22]: 
   ID         name
0   1      Company
1   1  Company,LLC
2   2   Companybbb
3   2  Company,LLC
4   3   Companyccc
5   3  Company,LLC

df.groupby('ID')['name'].transform('first')
Out[21]: 
0       Company
1       Company
2    Companybbb
3    Companybbb
4    Companyccc
5    Companyccc
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Comment: You can avoid the lambda here by using `.transform('first')`

Comment: @JonClements thanks for the reminder, always starting x.first() which fails then I fall back to head :-)

Answer (score 0):

For your example:

```
df.loc[df.name == 'Company, LLC', 'name'] = 'Company'
```

You can use this same method repeatedly to remap a sequence of values. As mentioned by [MattR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587311/pandas-convert-name-where-id-is-the-same-and-the-name-is-different#comment72306839_42587311), [FuzzyWuzzy](http://chairnerd.seatgeek.com/fuzzywuzzy-fuzzy-string-matching-in-python/) can help you find strings that are likely candidates for being identical, if you want to identify more potential matches.